# istio 1.4.8: strange 400 error when used with AWS Load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, envoyproxy

I'm getting a strange `400` error when I try to connect to an `Istio Gateway` when behind an `AWS` load balancer.

I don't see any activity in the `istio-ingresgateway` logs (even with debug settings on), but when I run `sysdig` on the `ingressgateway` pod, I see weird semi-random text with often with `"QUIT !T"` in it.

I get this when I try to make an `http` request via a browser or `curl` from outside the cluster.

The same `Istio` configuration works when I try to make the request in `minikube` or in `Azure`.

I'm also able to use the same `AWS` lb to point to a `Nginx` ingress controller and it works just fine.

```
sudo sysdig -s2000 -A -c echo_fds fd.ip=10.1.2.3
```

Sometimes there is no GET request in the output

```
------ Read 100B from   10.1.1.3:44404->10.1.2.3:80 (envoy)




QUIT
!T
C
ct>
------ Write 66B to   10.1.1.3:44404->10.1.2.3:80 (envoy)

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
content-length: 0
connection: close
```

And, sometimes this happens right before the `GET` request

```
------ Read 3.39KB from   10.1.1.3:35430->10.1.2.3:80 (envoy)




QUIT
!T
C
atfI>GET /myapp/ HTTP/1.1
```

I'm wondering if the weird characters are causing the `envoy` routes not to match, but I have no idea where this could be coming from.

Any advice as to what this might be?

Any general strategies for debugging `Istio` ingress?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the istio version? just to know. Thanks

Comment: The istio version is 1.4.8

Comment: Thanks. Is this LB a different one from the one that istio automatically deploys? Also, there were many fixes in version 1.5.1.

Comment: Thank you. We are using the default loadbalancer Service resource provided by the Istio installation, but due to our setup needs, we aren't able to use the automatic feature. We manually create the load balancer and connect to the NodePort that the service exposes. This has worked for us well for us in other clouds and when using the Nginx ingress controller. I'd like to use Istio 1.5, but need some time to form an upgrade path.

Answer (score 2):

So I found the answer to this question. The garbage in the request was a read herring.

A little more info about the setup:

The AWS load balancer was terminating TLS, so all the traffic behind it was going over the http port 31380. I was already passing the `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` header via the istio VirtualService setting, so the backend applications could assume that the traffic was already-terminated TLS traffic.

The solution:

The issue in my case was that the AWS Target Group had the `Proxy protocol v2: Enabled` set on it.  Turning this off solved the issue.

Comment: bless your soul... this just ended a multi-hour hunt for me :)